# How do I convert integers in a list to float numbers when the elements contain both words and numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, list

The list is ['Australia, 529\n', 'Jamaica, 466\n', 'England, 450\n', 'New Zealand, 391\n', 'South Africa, 363']

How do I convert only the numbers to floats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the numbers like this:

```
result = []
for item in input_list:
    country, number = item.split(',')
    float_number = float(number.rstrip('\n'))
    updated_element = f"{country}, {float_number}\n"
    result.append(updated_element)
print(result)
```

For your input list this will output:

```
['Australia, 529.0\n', 'Jamaica, 466.0\n', 'England, 450.0\n', 'New Zealand, 391.0\n', 'South Africa, 363.0\n']
```

To form a dictionary you can do this:

```
result_dict = {}
for item in input_list:
    country, number = item.split(',')
    float_number = float(number.rstrip('\n'))
    updated_element_dict = {country: float_number}
    result_dict.update(updated_element_dict)   
print(result_dict)
```

Above code will output:

```
{'Australia': 529.0, 'Jamaica': 466.0, 'England': 450.0, 'New Zealand': 391.0, 'South Africa': 363.0}
```

Comment: From this new list, how do I convert it into a dictionary where the output is {'Australia': 529.0, 'Jamaica': 466.0, 'England': 450.0, 'New Zealand': 391.0, 'South Africa': 363.0}
Note: I already stripped the \n from the list previously

Comment: Edited the response to show how to form also a dictionary. If you don't have the `\n` anymore you can remove `.rstrip('\n')` part.

Comment: Hi Dan, the code you provided me gives the output: 
{'Australia': 529.0}

{'Australia': 529.0, 'Jamaica': 466.0}

{'Australia': 529.0, 'Jamaica': 466.0, 'England': 450.0}

{'Australia': 529.0, 'Jamaica': 466.0, 'England': 450.0, 'New Zealand': 391.0}

{'Australia': 529.0, 'Jamaica': 466.0, 'England': 450.0, 'New Zealand': 391.0, 'South Africa': 363.0}

How do I make it so I only get the last dictionary in the output?

Comment: Make sure the `print` function is outside of the for loop, like in the example. It needs to be on the same indentation level as the for word. After the for loop is executed,  `result_dict` will contain only the last dictionary from your above comment.